# Компиляция под Android в Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, android-sdk

Раньше как-то работало. Но вот решил снова вернуться к работе с Android и при компиляции выводит вот такую замечательную ошибку:

> [Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBase2017\IDE_spoof;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBase2017\IDE_spoof;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBase2017\IDE_spoof;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\7.0\bin;C:\MyDocuments\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bpl\Win64;C:\Program Files\Ruby\bin;D:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;D:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl;C:\Program Files\Ruby\bin;C:\Users\Aptyp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; & "D:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\25.0.0\dx.bat" --dex --output="D:\TestAndroid\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "d:\program files\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" " exited with code 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась полным удалением всех версий Java и установкой 1 версии.